# shiny app with own function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I want to implement a function in a `Shiny` app. My own function `get_calculate()` has the arguments data and tolerance as input and retruns a `list` with a `data.frame` and a `plot`.

I want to show the output depending on tolerance. In my server function I use `reactive()` to run `get_calculate()` but it doesn't work.

If I write in `renderPlot()` and `renderDataTable()` `get_calculate()` works. 
For large datasets, however, it's inefficient because `Shiny` will have to run `get_calculate()` twice.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(foreign)
#load my own function
source("01-get_calculate.R")


ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Analysis"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Load data", tabName = "data", icon = icon("database")),
      menuItem("Mainboard", tabName = "Mainboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "data",
              fileInput("datafile", "Choose file",
                        accept = c("text/csv/rds/dbf", 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),

              dataTableOutput("mytable")

      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Mainboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  title = "Input", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                  sliderInput(inputId = "tol",
                              label = "Tolerance",
                              value = 4, min = 1, max = 15, step = 1)
                )),
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  title = "Adherence Curve", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                  plotOutput("plot_kpm")
                ),

                box(
                  title = "Overview Table", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                  tableOutput("table_kpm")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)
)



server <- function(input, output) {


  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.dbf(infile$datapath)
  })



  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    filedata()
  })

  **test <- reactive({
    get_calculate(filedata(), tolerance = input$tol)
  })

  output$plot_kpm <- renderPlot({ 
    test$kpm_chart
  })

  output$table_kpm <- renderDataTable({
    test$data_kpm[, c("Time", "numbers", "Percent")]
  })**


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: try `source("01-get_calculate.R", local = TRUE`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The shiny app still doesn't works. Error message in shiny app is: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: maybe `infile <- req(input$datafile)` instead of the `if(is.null(infile))`

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is most likely from renderDataTable where you are trying to pick couple of columns from test$data_kpm. Check the dataframe for exact column names.

Comment: The names are correct. When I use my own function both in renderDatatable and renderplot shiny apps works, but for large dataset it's very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This version of my shiny app runs. But it' ineffcient because shiny have to runs get_calculate twice.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  #This function is repsonsible for loading in the selected file
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.dbf(infile$datapath)
  })



  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    filedata()
  })

  output$plot_kpm <- renderPlot({
    get_calculate(filedata(), tolerance = input$tol)$kpm_chart
  })

 output$table_kpm <- renderTable({
    get_calculate(filedata(), tolerance = input$tol)$data_kpm[, c("Time", "Percent", "Patients")]
  })


 output$download_mainboard_adherence_table <- downloadHandler(
                                               filename = paste("adherence_table", '.csv', sep=''),
                                               content = function(file) {
                                                 write.csv(get_calculate(filedata(), tolerance = input$tol)$data_kpm[, c("Time", "Percent", "Patients")], file)
   }
 )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a reactive expression to run your get_calculate just once ? And then use the result in your output$plot_kpm and output$table_kpm ?
This will optimize your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what i do in my first example? But shiny app doesn't work. Error message in shiny app both on plot and table is: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: It is kind of hard answering without any reproducible example.

Comment: Did you try test()$kpm_chart instead of test$kpm_chart ?